# Dynamic showing table rows and CSS odd/even matching

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I have classic bootstrap html table with `.table-striped` class - it means zebra-striping (every even row has different color than odd).

On same site is filter witch show or hide rows in this table (it depends on filled inputs)

So from table wtih rows like this:

[image]

I get rows like this:

[image]

How I can resolve this problem? Is there some CSS way to do it? I can see solution with jquery iteration each row and change background-color but 
it seems to me as dirty solution.

EDIT:

CSS in bootstrap says:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

I hiding rows like this:

```
var tableRows = $('#myTable');
    tableRows.each(function() {
        if(condition) {
            $(this).hide();
            ...
```

Comment: is there any hidden rows in between?

Comment: yes... they are hidden

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding below script to manage hidden rows,

```
$("tr:not(.hidden)").each(function (index) {
    $(this).toggleClass("stripe", !!(index & 1));
});
```

Add this script on load and when ever you are hide/show the row

Comment: I must change selector from "tr:not(.hidden)" to "tr:visible" and overload default bootstrap behavior (CSS)... But looks like it works. If anybody don't write answer without overload bootstrap css i accept this answer. thx

Comment: @LajdákMarek this is one way of solving the problem  there must be an other way though, yr welcome